# Time series connected scatter plot in R (as image attached)

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I want to plot these data [image] as connected temporal scatter kind of plot in R. Any hint/code would be greatly helpful. I can do with single but not with time series one. [image]

Comment: Could you provide a sample dataset in your question? You will also need a table which maps the cities in your unnamed left hand column to the continents shown in the graph.

Comment: With regard to plotting the data if you use the tidyverse approach you will need to use `dplyr::pivot_longer` to transform the temporal population data into 'tidy' format so three variables become two: 'year' and 'population'. Plotting tidy data with `ggplot2` is straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you can apply this to your data.

I've assumed that it is not important that the years are treated as 'time' data for the purposes of graphical representation.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

pop <- tibble(city = c("Delhi", "Madurai", "Cape Town", "Jo Burg"),
              `1990` = c(10, 12, 5, 6),
              `2000` = c(13, 17, 7, 8),
              `2015` = c(20, 24, 7.5, 9),
              km2_1990 = c(12, 15, 2, 4),
              km2_2000 = c(13, 14, 3, 4),
              km2_2015 = c(15, 16, 5, 6))


cont <- tibble(city = c("Delhi", "Madurai", "Cape Town", "Jo Burg"),
               cont = c("Asia", "Asia", "Africa", "Africa"))


tib <- 
  pop %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = `1990`:km2_2015, names_to = "year", values_to = "val") %>% 
  mutate(type = case_when(str_detect(year, "km") ~ "area",
                          TRUE ~ "pop"),
         year = as.numeric(str_remove(year, "km2_"))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = val) %>% 
  left_join(cont) %>% 
  group_by(year, cont) %>% 
  summarise(area = sum(area),
            pop = sum(pop)) %>% 
  group_by(cont) %>% 
  mutate(lab_cont = case_when(pop == max(pop)~cont,
                              TRUE ~ ""))



ggplot(tib, aes(area, pop, label = lab_cont))+
  geom_line(aes(group = cont), colour = "red")+
  geom_point(fill = "red", colour = "red", shape = 22, size = 4)+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = year))+
  geom_text_repel(nudge_x = 1, size = 5)
```

This gives you the following graph, you can adjust arguments as required to pretty up the appearance to suit your purposes:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Transform your data like this

[image]

Then, plot using ggplot2 package.

```
mydata %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=bsurf, y=pop, group=city, color=city, dlabel=year)) + geom_point(,size = 2)+
  geom_line(size=1)+ geom_text(label=mydata$year, vjust = 1.2, nudge_y = 0.5)+
  ggtitle("Dummy Title", subtitle = "Dummy") + xlab("Population") + ylab("Total Built-up Surface")
```

[image]